# OpenApi Validate array of integers

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an endpoint, that takes array of numbers in json body.
These numbers represent `hours` (0 for 00:00; 1 for 01:00; ... ; 23 for 23:00(11:00PM))

```
{
    "hours": [
        7,
        14
    ]
}
```

I want to validate, that numbers in request are in the range of 0-23 on API level (so it wont be even mapped to Dto, if number is not inside the range)

I tried to define it like:

```
HoursDto:
  type: object
  properties:
    hours:
      type: array
      items:
        type: integer
        minimum: 0
        maximum: 23
```

But this has no effect - numbers outside the range are stilled mapped.

I guess problem is with validation being inside an array for each item.

So how can I validate each item of an array in OpenApi?

Comment: Your API definition is correct, so this looks like a tooling issue/limitation. Where exactly does this have no effect? Do you mean the code generated from this definition does not include min/max validations? If so, which code generator did you use?

Comment: @Helen exactly. Generated code has no annotations regarding minimum, maximum setting. It's Spring application so we use "spring" generator